# How to execute RFT scripts on a remote machine

Tags: automated-tests, rft

I have Rational Functional Tester installed on my local machine, and I have written some scripts. I need to run these scripts on a remote machine.

Research shows I should be:

> using RATIONAL TEST MANAGER

but the Rational Test Manager is now obsolete, since 2010.

I tried putting the scripts on RQM and run it through the web on remote machine, but for scripts to run from RQM we need an adapter which resides on the local machine.

How do I run my RFT scripts on a remote machine without installing RFT there?

Answer (score 0):

[execute rft test script using agent controller?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12767663/execute-rft-test-script-using-agent-controller)

"Post RFT 8.2.0.1 , to be able to execute a script on a remote machine RFT must be installed on that machine.

*****EDIT***
RFT's installation is a complete package installation ,meaning when you install RFT it installs a complete product that is capable of recording /playback scripts on all the supported domains.

So it's not possible to say that on this machine X install only the recorder and on the machine Y install only the playback engine.
Another approach perhaps could be to have some kind of tool on the server machine that would say that here is the script , go and execute on the machine Z , that does not have RFT installed .. but as the script may have controls recorded for all the domains (html/java/.net/SAP/Win32) all the supporting files DLLs /JARs (consiting of proxies and OS related shared libraries) would have to be transferred to that machine and that I think would be quite a task to do :) . So in my opinion it's not impossible but it's just not been done yet."

Answer Two:
"Wrong, it is not impossible. Just takes a lot of configuration. http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21319598

To execute RFT scripts on a remote machine: Make sure the scripts (java or .net ) are compiled before deploy for remote execution. After they are compiled successfully, In order to start remote execution, on the master machine, the Test Manager needs to be installed and configured correctly.

The following is the configuration on the TM on the master machine: In the "Execution" tab, right click on "Computers", and add new computer,specify the computer name, property, and the port information, so TM will be able to locate the remote machine. The set up for the remote machine will be described separately for java script and .net script. For java script, the following is needed on the remote machine: Test Manager Test Agent. (can be installed from Test manager CD). Rational Functional Tester Test Agent.( can be installed from RFT installation package). For .net script, the following is needed on the remote machine: Test Manager Test Agent. (can be installed from Test manager CD). Rational Functional Tester Test Agent.( can be installed from RFT installation package). .Net framework.(Visual Studio is not needed on the remote machine, there is currently defect on this, reference to a separate tech note on the workaround for this, searching "remote execution with .net script").

Last, but not the least, If the customer's AUT is Windows/.net/SAP based, then .net framework needs to be installed on the remote machine regardless whether it is java scripting or .net scripting. This is because some part of RFT's code gets placed into the application during infestation, the RFT code for these applications are written in C#, so at run time, the .net framework is needed to playback successfully."

Comment: Thanks a lot TJF ! That helped!